# Admin password rotation - Community Edition

Tags: magento-community, magento1.9.2.4, magento-ce

**Magento EE** has a feature to force **admin** users to automatically rotate their passwords every X number of days.

Anyone know of an extension that would do the same for a CE site ?

Answer (score -1):

You can  do better, how about 2FA?

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/two-factor-authentication.html

Comment: I've downvoted this answer as it does not solve the problem. 2FA is not a replacement for password lifetime, which is a PCI requirement (8.2.4)

Comment: Harsh but a good insight on PCI. The question did not mention that the goal was to get their password PCI compliant and that was not inferred.